# Google chrome doesn't load analytics.js

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-analytics

I am developping an Angular 6 application, and I want to use Google Analytics on it. The problem is that google chrome does not load the analytics.js script and gives the following error message:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

I want to note that the script works very well in Opera with VPN activated. Here is the script I added to the `index.html` file

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX-ID', 'auto');
</script>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Check that if your chrome has any add-block extension. Try to run in incognito mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your chrome is under a proxy, please check.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in other browsers
Check to see if you have any extensions running
There are several blockers that do not allow access to trackers like Google Analytics
I turn all of mine off when I need to test

Comment: I have already uninstalled all my extensions and I also tried to run it in incognito mode but it has not resolve my problem.

Comment: Perhaps if you can, have another person try on their machine just to be sure.  
There may be something in your settings.  If it works in Opera, it should be OK in chrome. I'm not an expert, but that is all I could think of to help narrow it down.